# Re-Index Elasticsearch, ignore fields not in mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to test out re-index API in elasticsearch and running into issues where existing data contains fields not present in the new index's strict mapping.  Is there a way to tell elasticsearch to simply ignore those fields and carry on?

Edit: To clarify, by ignore I meant not to include those fields during the re-index process.

Comment: can you adjust the mapping settings before starting the reindex? or you don't have access to it?

Comment: @AndreyBorisko I can but I want the fields ignored, or i guess removed, during the re-index.  Is that even possible?

Comment: it's possible. might look dirty though. depending on how many properties you need to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the index settings before running `reindex` you can just do:

```
PUT test/_mapping
{
    "dynamic": "false"
}
```

then change it back to `strict` once reindexing is done.

UPDATE based on your comment

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "src"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dst"
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": """
    ctx['_source'].remove('email');
    ctx['_source'].remove('username');
    ctx['_source'].remove('name');
    // removing from nested:
    for(item in ctx['_source'].Groups){
        item.remove('GroupName');
        item.remove('IsActive');
    }
    """
  }
}
```

Comment: That lets me insert the data, however I would like any excess fields removed.

Comment: It seems you have to specify the individual fields you want versus remove anything not in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

While reindexing you can include or exclude source fields according to your destination index mapping.

To exclude some specific fields while reindexing:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source-index",
    "_source": {
      "excludes": ["exclude_a", "exclude_b"]
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest-index"
  }
}
```

To include any specific field while reindexing:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source-index",
    "_source": ["include_a", "include_b"]
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest-index"
  }
}
```